# anchor link from a image carousel to toggle div on products page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JS and know little bit of HTML/CSS so any help is really appreciated. I got a weeks time to publish my website on server

I got the things working, as I like. It expands/collapses very well and I am happy with the result. The problem I am facing is, I have a image carousel on my website and want to link it to the divs.

For example: when a visitor clicks on image2, it should go to test2 and test 1 should be collapsed.

HTML Code

```
<p class="trigger"><a href="#!">Test1</a></p>
<div class="toggle_container" id="1">
<div class="block">
    <p>Contents of test1 to be displayed</p>        
</div>
<div>
<p class="trigger"><a href="#!">Test2</a></p>
<div class="toggle_container" id="2">
<div class="block">
    <p>Contents of test2 to be displayed</p>        
</div>
<div>
```

CSS

```
p.trigger{
margin-bottom:7px;
margin-top:-5px;
color: #545454;
text-decoration: none;
}

.toggle_container{
margin-bottom:10px;
}

.toggle_container p{
margin:0px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.toggle_container{
background:#f0f0f0;
clear: both;
font-size:100%;
}

p.trigger a {
color: #545454;
text-decoration: none;
}

p.trigger a:link, p.trigger a:visited {
color: #545454;
text-decoration: none;
}

p.trigger a:hover, p.trigger a:active {
color: #ff00ff;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".toggle_container:not(:first)").hide();

$("p.trigger").on('click', function(){
$('.toggle_container').slideUp().eq($(this).index('p.trigger')).stop().slideToggle();
return false;
});
```

Did lot of searches and tried lot of codes, but nothing worked for me. Please help!!! Thank you

http://jsfiddle.net/bL9Le/ doesn't seem to be working but works on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution. Just to help others, here is the code

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash != "") {
        var id = hash.substr(1);
        $(".toggle_container:not(:active)").hide();
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had several mistakes in that fiddle. Your divs were not closed and jQuery was not selected to be used within the fiddle. [Check this out as an alternative solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/bL9Le/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".toggle_container").hide();

    $(".trigger").on('click', function(e)
    {
        $('.toggle_container').slideUp(500, function()
        {
            $(e.target).next('.toggle_container').slideDown(500);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you very much Serg but this is not a problem. The problem is, how do I link this div to an external navigation. Like, I have an image on homepage, when I click on it, it should go to products page and expand the test 2. Rest all should be collapsed.